# How to displaying u and v components of wind data from a grib file as geoserver coverage?

Tags: geoserver, sld, grib

I have generated a coverage view from a grib file (u,v components), but I can't style the result of both components.

Is there any way to style both wind components (u and v)?

My style is the next one:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
<NamedLayer>
<Name>Many color gradient</Name>
<UserStyle>
<Title>SLD Cook Book: Many color gradient</Title>
<FeatureTypeStyle>
<Rule>
<RasterSymbolizer>
   <ChannelSelection>
            <GrayChannel>
                    <SourceChannelName>2</SourceChannelName>
            </GrayChannel>
    </ChannelSelection>
<ColorMap type="ramp" extended="true">
<ColorMapEntry color="#6470a9" quantity="0"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#5979a9" quantity="2"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#5997a6" quantity="6"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#629683" quantity="10"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#59a159" quantity="14"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#5ba759" quantity="17"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#a89e59" quantity="21"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#a88e59" quantity="25"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#9d6f61" quantity="29"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#915968" quantity="33"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#a75986" quantity="37"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#85689e" quantity="41"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#72699e" quantity="47"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#667f9f" quantity="52"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#6b949e" quantity="56"/>
<ColorMapEntry color="#8659a9" quantity="194"/>
</ColorMap>
</RasterSymbolizer>
</Rule>

</FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

If i change  the 1 then i can see the other component but i can't mix them.
Any ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you can find something useful from here http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/rtx/wind_arrows.html

Comment: Thank you, but this creating barbs, I need to create a raster image from u,v components. The result of the image must be sqrt(u^2 + v^2).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the above problem using ras:Jiffle script as follows:

```
    <Transformation>
      <ogc:Function name="ras:Jiffle">
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>script</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>
            u = src[0];
            v = src[1];
            dest = sqrt(u*u+v*v) * 0.01;               
          </ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function> 
      </ogc:Function>
    </Transformation>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:RasterSymbolizer>   
        <ColorMap>
          <ColorMapEntry color="#5E70B4" quantity="0" opacity="1.0"/>
          <ColorMapEntry color="#3B68A1" quantity="1" opacity="1.0"/>
          <ColorMapEntry color="#4078A5" quantity="2" opacity="1.0"/>              
        </ColorMap>
      </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
```